# Read value from application.properties into Spring Batch Reader?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am developing **Spring Batch Oracle 12c** example, in this reader, I wanted to pass value 60 as a placeholder, if this value changes in future, I should be able to handle it from the application.properties file rather than using it in the sql query as hardcode value.

```
<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false" />
<property name="fetchSize" value="50" />
<property name="sql">
    <value>
            <![CDATA[
            SELECT data.Acc_NUM, data.FD_NUM FROM FD_DATA data, BATch_JOB_RUN B,
            CASE WHEN (data.crte_dt + 60 > sysdate) then 'YES' else 'NO' End DONT_CONSIDER
            WHERE data.ONLINE_ID is NULL and data.updt_dt > B.RUN_DT    
            ]]>
    </value>
</property>
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="com.XXX.XXX.mapper.BankDataVOMapper"
        scope="step" />
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You can put to stepExecutionContext. You can have beforeStep listener to inject if you want

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that using below code.

```
<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false" />
<property name="fetchSize" value="50" />
<property name="sql">
    <value>
            <![CDATA[
            SELECT data.Acc_NUM, data.FD_NUM FROM FD_DATA data, BATch_JOB_RUN B,
            CASE WHEN (data.crte_dt + (#{stepExecutionContext[days60]}) > sysdate) then 'YES' else 'NO' End DONT_CONSIDER
            WHERE data.ONLINE_ID is NULL and data.updt_dt > B.RUN_DT    
            ]]>
    </value>
</property>
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="com.XXX.XXX.mapper.BankDataVOMapper" scope="step" />
</property>
</bean>
```

Also I used the below code in the Step Execution:

```
ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
executionContext.put("days60", 60);
```